# Is there anybody who can help me with mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, pivot

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(kwh) FROM energy_logger WHERE TIME >= '05:30:00' AND TIME < '18:30:00' GROUP BY Date) as daytime,
    (SELECT SUM(kwh) FROM energy_logger WHERE TIME >= '18:30:00' AND TIME < '22:30:00' GROUP BY Date) as peaktime,
    (SELECT SUM(kwh) FROM energy_logger WHERE TIME >= '22:30:00' OR TIME < '05:30:00' GROUP BY Date) offpeaktime, 
    Date 
FROM energy_logger 
GROUP BY Date 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

This is my query!
And I always have an issue of this, "Subquery returns more than 1 row".....

Comment: I'm thinking you might need to use the subqueries in left joins instead.

Comment: It means that `SELECT SUM(kwh) FROM energy_logger WHERE TIME >= '05:30:00' AND TIME < '18:30:00' GROUP BY Date)` (and the two subqueries below it) could potentially return more than one row in their own results. Therefore, how you can put that into a single field in a single row within the outer SELECT query? It's not logical. That's what the error is telling you. If you want to use a subquery to generate a single value then you must ensure the subquery can only ever return one row. But as others mention, you probably don't actually need subqueries here at all.

Comment: P.S. I changed your tags because this question is just about SQL. It has nothing to do with PHP or XAMPP. You might be using those technologies elsewhere in your application but they are not involved in this problem. If you tag your questions accurately, they are more likely to be seen by people with the right skills to help you. If you use the wrong tags, you'll be likely to get less help, and it'll annoy people who try to read a question that means nothing to them!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for conditional aggregataion:

```
select 
    date,
    sum(case when time '05:30:00' and time < '18:30:00' then kwh end) daytime,
    sum(case when time '18:30:00' and time < '22:30:00' then kwh end) peaktime,
    sum(case when time '22:30:00' or  time < '05:30:00' then kwh end) offpeaktime
from energy_logger 
group by date
order by date
```

This will give you, for each day, the sum of `kwh` over the 3 distinct time slots (daytime, peaktime, offpeaktime).

Comment: let me try, but i think your answer is what i want !!